# How to read the value of childByAutoId() in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to iOS development, I am storing a chunk of data to firebase database by using childByAutoId(), below this am storing username, photoURL, textMessage and user UID. I am retrieving this data in tableView Cells. Now what I want is when I tap one of the posts or tableView cells, I want to print the unique ID generated by childByAutoId() function. How to do this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let name = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Trial", message: "You Selected "+name!, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close Alert", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I am using this code to catch taps on cells. So what is that code that will help in getting the child ID of that particular cell after tapping it?
I want to print it in logs.

[image]

This is how my list looks like.

Comment: So baiscally you want to print the value of child id that was in firebase DB ? or the unique id of the cell ?

Comment: child id in firebase database @RahimKhalid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to access the key of any particular data, you have to make a firebase query. And i believe that you have some unique value to identify your data.

For the purpose of getting the unique key, you can use this func :

```
func getUniqueFirebaseKey(){
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("CHILD_NAME")
    .queryEqual(toValue: "UNIQUE_ID")
    .observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in`

        if let snap = snapShot.value as? [String:Any] {

            for key in snap.keys{
                return key
            }
    })
}
```

By this you can get your auto ID key of firebase.

But the better option is to create a model and store that key while parsing the data from firebase.

Comment: Now suppose I tap 0th cell, then with this info how can I get child ID assigned to it. @Rahim Khalid

Comment: With 0th cell you have some object, like name, message, time ,and other stuff right ?

Comment: With the above code I am able to retrieve all the child id's but I want to retrieve the specific child id of the post,  one that was tapped. @Rahim Khalid

Comment: Ok, so you have all the objects of Post in an array which you are using for the purpose of populating the table. So you can access the data as postArray[indexPath.row].autoId

Comment: can you give me the line of code, my array name is var posts = [Post]() and Post is separate file that has class Post and init() function with rest info like username, text and so on. @Rahim Khalid

Comment: posts[indexPath.row].autoId
*replace autoId by the property you have used for parsing autoId*

Comment: Perfect! it works, thanks a lot. I used it as posts[indexPath.row].theAutoKey as String. Now its returning the specific key. Thank You. @Rahim Khalid

Answer (score 0):

Every cell has an indexPath that has information about its row and section:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Side note: the name of a user shouldn't be optional 
    let name = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName ?? ""
    let message = "You Selected " + name + " in cell number : " + \(indexPath.row) 

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Trial", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close Alert", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!, With this code am getting the index of each row say 0,1,2,3, but I want to access the key assigned to it @Carpsen90